# flask blueprint - database call gives Object has no attribute 'query' error

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new at flask Blueprints, and I am getting the error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'query'. I am pretty sure that it is some thing simple that I am missing.  I believe that my error is coming from the views.py file, and that db is not accessed, but I am not sure why. **'From project import db'** should be doing this.  I think.

Thank you for the help

Here is the code.

**app.py**

```
from project import app
if __name__ == 'main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
db = SQLALchemy

from project.ContentType.views import ContentType_BP
app.register_blueprint(ContentType_BP, url_prefix='/ContentType')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from project.ContentType.forms import ContentTypeForm
from project.models import ContentType
from project import db

ContentType_BP = Blueprint('ContentType',__name__, 
                           template_folder = 'templates')

@ContentType_BP.route('/ContentType', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ContentType():
    form = ContentTypeForm()
    results = ContentType.query.all() ## this is were my error occurs 

    return render_template('contenttype/contenttype.html',
                            form=form, results=results)
```

**Models.py**

```
from project import db
class ContentType(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
ct1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
ct2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Below is the directory tree.  I thought it might come in handy.  '--' represents a sub-directory for Main

```
Main
  app.py
  __init__.py
  --project
     models.py
     --ContentType
       __init__.py
       --static
       --templates
         --ContentType
            contenttype.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are shadowing `ContentType` from your db model classes, since you are using it as the name of the view.

Try changing the name of the view:

`def ContentType():`

to something like:

`def content_type():`

and using that name instead.